# Liouville theorem for linear equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\Omega$ denote a an exterior domain in $R^N$ with smooth boundary.
I am interested in Liouville Theorems related to smooth solutions of

$$\Delta \phi(x) + \gamma \sum_{i,j=1}^N \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^2} \phi_{x_i x_j}(x) =0$$ in $\Omega$ with $ \phi=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$ and under the assumption that $ \sup_\Omega |x|^{\sigma+1} | \nabla \phi(x)| \le C$.       The domain does not contain the origin in its closure.

In the case of $\Omega$ the compliment of the unit ball centred at the origin I can get exact (and optimal) conditions on $\gamma$ and $\sigma$ that give me a Liouville theorem (one writes $ \phi$ with spherical harmonics and then examines the ODE's).

In the case of $\gamma=0$  but a general domain I work on $\Omega_R:=\{x \in \Omega: |x|<R\}$ and multiply $-\Delta \phi$ by $ \phi$ and integrate by parts and then use the bound on $\phi$ to control the boundary terms on $B_R$.   This gives an optimal result.

In the case of $ \gamma>0$ and general domain I can try and copy the same approach but it appears either I won't get anything, or at least I won't get optimal results.

QUESTION.   Is there a general approach to trying to prove these things?   If I let
$$ \psi(r) = \int_{|\theta|=1} \phi(r \theta) d \theta$$ for $ r>0$ big enough so $ \partial B_r \subset \Omega$ I see  (under the expected assumptions on $\gamma$ and $ \sigma$)  that $ \psi(r)$ is constant. Of course since the domain isn't radial its hard to use this for much.

Is there any hope of using a continuity argument to connect the general case to the radial case?

thanks for all comments.

Comment: The operator is symmetric with respcet to the measure $|x|^r\, dx$ with $r=\frac{N-1}{\gamma+1}-N+1$. Variational computations could be easier here, but I do not know if the new measure fits well with your assumptions.

Comment: Thank  you very much for the comment.   I had done something similar (but with a change of dimension)  but then I got confused with the Laplace-Beltrami operator.     Maybe your approach will allow me to copy the Laplacian approach;  I will try.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune.   I checked it and it appears this gives me exactly what I want..i think.   Thank you very much.  If you cut and paste your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Good if it works. It is not really an answer but only a suggestion how to go on, having done similar computations.